# No Cardano Wallet commands are working

Tags: wallet

I have a testnet cardano node up and running  - fully synced, however when I query the network for cardano-wallet commands i am getting

ConnectionError (HttpExceptionRequest Request {
host                 = "localhost"
port                 = 8090
secure               = False
requestHeaders       = [("Accept","application/json;charset=utf-8,application/json")]
path                 = "/v2/network/information"
queryString          = ""
method               = "GET"
proxy                = Nothing
rawBody              = False
redirectCount        = 10
responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutDefault
requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
(ConnectionFailure Network.Socket.connect: <socket: 11>: does not exist (Connection refused)))

Comment: Apparently you have to run cardano-wallet serve for some of teh commands to work. However, I tried running it and it keeps shutting down

 get this error

cardano-wallet: ExceptionInLinkedThread (ThreadId 15) DecoderFailure (LocalStateQuery HardForkBlock (': ....

Comment: I used the followinng command with no success

cardano-wallet serve   --testnet /home/user/cardano/testnet-byron-genesis.json   --node-socket /home/user/cardano/db/node.socket   --database /home/user/cardano/db

Comment: Can you check port 8090 is in use?

Comment: No.. That port is not in use

Comment: Here is an screenshot of the error

https://imgur.com/a/BPOKY7J

Comment: It says "Running as v2021.5.26" in the logs, maybe you need to update the binary?

Comment: what version should it be?